# how to debug gstreamer without slowing down the device

Tags: linux, debugging, gstreamer, timing

Now I am using GST_DEBUG to debug my plugin on an embedded device. But when I open the debug micro, the out put messages will slow down the device. In this case, gstreamer internal logic may changed because of the timing change and I cannot reproduce the bug. So how to debug gstreamer without slowing down the device?

Answer (score 0):

To what are you setting GST_DEBUG? You can try to select just the categories and level you need. For that use e.g.

```
GST_DEBUG="cat1:level1,cat2:level2,..."
```

In your cases use the category you register for your plugin only.

Answer (score 0):

Use environment variable `GST_DEBUG_FILE` to tell GStreamer write debug messages to a file inside tmpfs (or RAM disk).
This trick can greatly improve the speed.

(Reference: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html)